# rasperry pi / debian / directory mount issue

Tags: linux, usb, debian, mount

I have trouble regarding to external USB disk write operations
I am using Rasperry Pi box with Debian Linux

```
root@raspberrypi:~# umount /dev/sda1
root@raspberrypi:~# mkdir /media/extGrayUSB
root@raspberrypi:~# mount -t ntfs /dev/sda1 /media/extGrayUSB/
root@raspberrypi:~# id
uid=0(root) gid=0(root) groups=0(root),1001(indiecity)
root@raspberrypi:~# 
root@raspberrypi:~# ls -la /media | grep ext
drwx------  1 root root 4096 May  1 18:01 extGrayUSB
root@raspberrypi:~# mkdir /media/extGrayUSB/hede
mkdir: cannot create directory `/media/extGrayUSB/hede': Operation not permitted
root@raspberrypi:~# 
root@raspberrypi:~# chmod 777 /media/extGrayUSB
root@raspberrypi:~# chmod 777 -R /media/extGrayUSB
root@raspberrypi:~# ls -la /media | grep ext
drwxrwxrwx  1 root root 4096 May  1 18:01 extGrayUSB
root@raspberrypi:~# mkdir /media/extGrayUSB/hede
mkdir: cannot create directory `/media/extGrayUSB/hede': Operation not permitted
root@raspberrypi:~# 

root@raspberrypi:/media# ls -la /media/extGrayUSB/
total 8
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root 4096 May  1 18:01 .
drwxr-xr-x 6 root root 4096 May  2 22:00 ..
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root    0 May  1 18:01 incoming
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root    0 May  1 18:01 temp
```

why I am getting this permission error ? I am root, I could mount ext USB drive but could not create any directory

Thanks for your helps

Comment: Not sure what ntfs driver you are using, but it may force it to be mounted read only if the dirty bit is set.  This would happen if it wasn't cleanly unmounted/removed from a Windows system.  Try plugging it back into a Windows system and then using the "Safely Remove Hardware" option in the taskbar before removing it.  It could also be that the ntfs driver in your kernel only supports reading it.

Comment: COuld you do a ls -la in the /media/extGrayUSB folder and post the results?   What is currently on that drive?  Are there files?   Is the folder empty?   what sorts of permissions are set on the files in /media/extGrayUSB?   Who owns those files? I am guessing root would since you mounted it as root, but I am interested to see if there are any other file/directory owners being listed.

Comment: @ultrasawblade : I was thinking like you, so I reformatted my USB with my notebook with ntfs. I am using RHEL on my notebook.
I umounted from notebook then try above commands

Comment: @Richie086 Actually I created 2 directories when I format my disk. ls output like following lines, I cannot remove the directories like could not create new directories
posted output in case history

Comment: Hello again

I reformatted external USB disk with notebook and tried mount/remount in notebook, created text file, edited/updated in text file. No problem

And then,  I have attached into rasperry but same problem still exist
The problem is on RasperryPi side but could not find out yet

Any idea ?

Best regards

Comment: Following up on LawrenceC's comment: what is the output from `mount`. Does it show RO ?

Answer (score -1):

Remount with ntfs-3g

```
umount /dev/sda1
sudo mount -t ntfs-3g /dev/sda2 /mnt/data
```